# SCardConnect (winscard.dll) is always returning error

Tags: c#, smartcard

I am trying to connect a smart card reader using following code

```
retCode = ModWinsCard.SCardConnect(hContext, cbReader.SelectedItem.ToString(), ModWinsCard.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED, ModWinsCard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | ModWinsCard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, ref hCard, ref Protocol);
```

But it is always returning some error code. First it was returning 6 after changing the target platform to x86 now it is returning -2146434967.

Any idea why its behaving so?

Comment: You may have more success considering the error code as unsigned (hex): 0x80100069; this means  "The smart card has been removed, so that further communication is not possible". ??

Comment: Yes you are right. This is due to the removal of Tag from the reader. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you put your solution? Thanks

Comment: @A.Vila I have added an answer, let me know if this resolves your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for other to benefit:-
This was due to the removal of tag from the reader.

You can keep you tag placed on the reader this error will get removed.

Answer (score 3):

Same code, returning 6 instead of 0.

Setting card on reader did not help until I did not change build option to x86.

Thank You for posting that changing target platform returned -2146434967 (0x80100069 - SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD).